# Testing date values with HSQLDB

Tags: java, sql-server, testing, integration-testing, hsqldb

We use SQLServer in production, but HSQLDB for our integration tests. HSQLDB is used because it's an in-memory database.

I have an SQLServer SQL that executes the following code:

```
select convert(varchar(8), pos_val_date, 112) 
from wscpos;
```

In HSQLDB, this does not work. The code should be:

```
select to_char( pos_val_date, 'YYYYMMDD')
from wscpos;
```

What's the best practice to adapt my code such that it runs both in production and in my integration test?

Comment: Use SQLServer Express for your tests and don't change the code at all

Comment: Use the same database for production and integration tests, if you actually want to see if your code will work.

Comment: I guess what the OP missed to mention is that they want an in-memory solution. I am not sure whether MS SQL can provide that.

Comment: Correct, I adapted the question to include that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inclined to change your DB for integration tests, I would recommend to adopt H2 using *MODE=MSSQLServer* which should provide a better compatibility against MS SQL Server, better than what HSQLDB gives you now.

Comment: very interesting, this did work for the simple example that I posted but I'm still having some incompatibilities as my SQL is more complex than the one shown in the question... but I'll be investigating that.