# HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: DATETIMEOFFSET

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb

I have a Java 8, Spring Boot 2 application with JPA entities connecting to a MS SQL Server database. I am trying to create integration tests using HSQLDB (2.3.3), which work fine if I do not include audit information (created date, last updated, etc.).

This is the error message that I get:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: DATETIMEOFFSET
```

I understand that the 'type not found or user lacks privilege' error is generic, and could be caused by a variety of things. In this case, I know that everything would otherwise run correctly if not for trying to add a datetimeoffset column to a table.

While looking for answers online I found [this documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html) that at least some MS SQL date/time types and functions are supported, but [this (two-year-old) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813537/testing-date-values-with-hsqldb) suggests that HSQLDB has only limited support for MS SQL. I haven't found any documentation that talks about HSQLDB specifically in relation to the datetimeoffset data type.

My Table Creation and Data Insertion Script:

```sql
    DROP SCHEMA TEST IF EXISTS;
    CREATE SCHEMA TEST;

    CREATE TABLE TEST.Example (
      ID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
      Name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
      Description nvarchar(1000),
      CreatedDate datetimeoffset(7) NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO TEST.Example (ID, Name, Description, CreatedDate) 
    VALUES (1, 'First', 'This is the first example.', '2019-04-18 12:00:00 -05:00');
```

My Datasource Configuration:

```
    config:
      datasource:
        jdbc-url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sys.syntax_mss=true
        driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
        validation-query: SELECT 1
        test-on-borrow: false
        test-while-idle: true
        time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
        max-active: 10
```

My Entity:

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Example", schema = "TEST")
    public class ExampleEntity {    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "Description")
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "CreatedDate", nullable = false)
        private LocalDateTime createdDate;    
    }
```

My Repository:

```java
    public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<ExampleEntity, Integer> {
    }
```

My Integration Test Configuration:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.test.example.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "integrationTestEntityFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "integrationTestTransactionManager")
    public class IntegrationTestConfig {
        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.datasource")
        public DataSource integrationTestDatasource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .addScript("scripts/schema.sql")
                .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean integrationTestEntityFactory(final DataSource integrationTestDatasource) {

            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
            vendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            factory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.example.entity");
            factory.setDataSource(integrationTestDatasource);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager integrationTestTransactionManager(final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean integrationTestEntityFactory) {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(integrationTestEntityFactory.getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }

        @Bean
        public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate integrationTestJdbcTemplate(final DataSource integrationTestDatasource) {
            return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(integrationTestDatasource);
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Read the documentation** of HSQLDB, not of SQL Server, if you want to learn what data types are supported: [HyperSQL User Guide - **Datetime types**](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_datetime_types). There is no such data type as `datetimeoffset`.

Comment: @Andreas I have read that, and it fails to mention that it doesn't support all of the features of SQL Server. Downvoting for lack of research when I have done my research and am still in need of help is petty and unnecessary. If you are suggesting that HSQLDB can not do what I need, then that sounds like the making of an answer that could help not just me but others with this problem in the future.

Comment: Where in your research did you find that HSQLDB supported the *data types* of SQL Server? The link you gave says *"HyperSQL 2.4 adds several **datetime functions** in MSS compatibility mode. These include DATEPART, DATENAME, EOMONTH and compatible DATEADD and DATEDIFF behaviour"*. Functions!!! Not data types. The "MS SQLServer and Sybase Compatibility" section doesn't mention column data types at all.

Comment: @Andreas It sounds like you're having a bad day. I'd appreciate it if you didn't ruin mine by preventing me from getting help. Or does this site not help people?

Comment: I'm helping by pointing out that you misread the documentation. Or, in case I did, I'm asking you to point me to where you believe the documentation said what you claimed it said *("I found this documentation that at least some MS SQL date/time **types** and functions are supported")*. Is pointing out mistakes not relevant to you? Don't reject **help** just because it points out you didn't understand something. Learn from it, i.e. don't try to use a SQL Server column data type in the DDL for HSQLDB.

Comment: Please note the HSQLDB Guide does not list ALL the compatibilty mode supported functions and type names, including this one. The OP's used version is older than the referenced doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of HSQLDB support DATETIMEOFFSET in MSS compatibility mode. Use 2.4.1.

If you want to continue using an older version that does not support this type, then use `CREATE TYPE DATETIMEOFFSET AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` before creating your tables.

Comment: This solved my problem. As a note, while SQL Server may use a precision input in the column definition, HSQLDB does not. This does mean that my test data won't be an exact match to production data, but combined with changing to OffsetDateTime per @MaciejKowalski, I don't think that will be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

For the `datetimeoffset` SQL type you should use the `java.time.OffsetDateTime` Java type:

```
    @Column(name = "CreatedDate", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime createdDate;
```

This is if you have JPA in version 2.2 in your classpath. Otherwise you would need to create a [custom converter](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)

Comment: I get the error even if I leave the field out of the entity. The error that I'm getting is definitely in HSQLDB creating the column, and not in JPA getting data out of the table.

Comment: I will work on creating a converter, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I added a converter, and I still have this issue.

Comment: I was using LocalDateTime based on existing work in my organization, but OffsetDateTime will work much better for my needs, and without a converter to boot. Your answer didn't specifically answer my question, but it was still great advice. Thanks for the help!